# RSpec 2.13.1 hanging in Ruby 1.9.3 with Rails 3.2.13 and Spork 1.0.0rc3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, spork

Trying to resurrect an old project by upgrading gems. Ran into an issue where RSpec hangs on startup with the '--drb' option.

By itself, 'rspec spec' works fine. But start 'spork' in another terminal and then 'rspec --drb spec' spins up CPU to ~40% and just sits.

Using Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 1.9.3-p392, RSpec 2.13.1 and spork-rails 3.2.1, which depends on Spork 1.0.0rc3.

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.13'

gem 'devise', '~> 2.2.0'
gem 'event-calendar', :require => 'event_calendar'
gem 'has_scope'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'validates_timeliness'

# deployment process management
gem 'foreman'
gem 'thin'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '< 2.0'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.13.1'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'growl'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'ruby-prof'
  gem 'test-unit'
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do

  # Prevent Devise from loading the User model super early with it's routes
  # see: https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujitsu
  require "rails/application"
  Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application::RoutesReloader, :reload!)

  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  # Since I have included Test::Unit for perfomance tests, disable auto-run
  Test::Unit::AutoRunner.need_auto_run = false if defined?(Test::Unit::AutoRunner)

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # ## Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
    # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
    # the seed, which is printed after each run.
    #     --seed 1234
    config.order = "random"
  end

end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

I'm not getting any error messages or feedback on the console, so I don't even know where to start looking for problems. Any suggestions?

Comment: Uh, this problem has gone away. I can't find any suitable explanation for the change. Am I crazy?

Comment: Uh, this problem has come back, but I've also discovered that I can only reproduce this on one of my two machines.

Comment: One machine has RVM for managing Rubies, the other uses rbenv... I'm going to try nuking my rubies altogether and rebuild... see if that does anything.

Comment: Completely nuked rbenv, all rubies and all gemsets; reinstalled; still hanging on the machine with rbenv. Is there anything I can do to get some more debug information?

Comment: Okay the issue appears to be related to the upgrade from ruby 1.9.2-p290 up to ruby 1.9.3-p392... All else constant, I can reproduce the issue under 1.9.3 but not under 1.9.2... with rbenv.

Comment: Tested additional patch levels on Ruby tonight and found that 1.9.3-p0 works, 1.9.3-p125 breaks. Also tested 1.9.3-p392 under RVM and found that works. So I tore everything down to pieces again and did a 'brew update'. Brew found a new version of ruby-build formula, dated today. Installed 1.9.3-p392 again with 'rbenv install 1.9.3-p392' and like magic, it worked. I'll tinker some more and see if I hit any walls.

Comment: Have you considered that Rails 3.2.13 is patched to support Ruby 2.0? I haven't come across any issues yet, but just to be safe I would use 3.2.12 -- the only difference between that and 3.2.13 are the patches to support Ruby 2.0. Give it a try.

Comment: @dimitko, I'm certain 3.2.13 contains more than Ruby 2.0.0 support; see release notes: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/3/18/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-13-3-1-12-and-2-3-18-have-been-released/

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading ruby-build via `brew update ruby-build` picked up a new version dated 2013-05-01. After the update, I trashed and reinstalled all my Rubies, and the problem seems to have resolved itself.

I don't know what specifically addressed the issue, but here are some notes and a relevant commit: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/commit/9f8d53365aef52c940095f583cdc82f02caba90f